# Are the Boolean algebras ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$ and ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{thin})$ isomorphic?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory, posets, boolean-algebras

A set $A\subseteq \omega$ is said to be *thin* if $$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap \{0,\ldots, n\}|}{n+1} = 0.$$

We say for $A, B\subseteq \omega$ that $A\simeq_\text{fin} B$ if the symmetric difference $A \, \triangle \, B$ is finite. It is easy to see that this an equivalence relation, and a routine verification shows that the resulting quotient is an atomless Boolean algebra. It is customarily denoted by ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$.

We can do exactly the same thing for thin sets by saying $A\simeq_{\text{thin}} B$ if $A \, \triangle \, B$ is thin. This gives rise to a Boolean algebra ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{thin})$.

**Question.** Are the Boolean algebras ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$ and ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{thin})$ isomorphic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is no.

In the Boolean algebra $P(\omega)/\text{Fin}$ every strictly descending sequence $A_0>A_1>A_2>\cdots$ has a nonzero lower bound, by the famous construction of Hausdorff. Namely, one can find an infinite set $A$ that is almost contained in every $A_n$. For example, let $A$ consist of the $n$th element of $A_0\cap A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ for every $n$. This is an infinite set, which after the $n$th point is contained in $A_n$.

But the Boolean algebra $P(\omega)/\text{Thin}$, in contrast, does not exhibit this feature, since we can arrange that the density of the sets converges to $0$, and in this case there can be no set with nonzero density that is below them all.

Here is another way to argue:

**Theorem.** The Boolean algebras $P(\omega)/\text{Fin}$ and $P(\omega)/\text{Thin}$ are not isomorphic, because:

1. There is no countably infinite maximal antichain in $P(\omega)/\text{Fin}$, but
2. There is a countably infinite maximal antichain in $P(\omega)/\text{Thin}$.

**Proof.** For 1, suppose that $A_0, A_1, A_2,\ldots$ is a countably infinite antichain. So these form an almost-disjoint family of infinite sets. Let $A$ choose one element from $A_n-\bigcup_{k<n}A_k$. So $A$ is an infinite set almost disjoint from each of them, showing it wasn't maximal.

For 2, let $A_n$ be all the numbers of the form $2^nr$, where $r$ is odd. So $A_0$ has density 1/2 and $A_1$ has density 1/4 and so forth. This is a partion of $\omega$, but every set with positive density will have positive density intersection with one of them, since if the density of $A$ exceeds that of the tail beyond $n$, then it must overlap nontrivially with some $A_k$ for $k<n$. $\Box$

Ultimately, the two argument methods can be seen as the same. For example, with the antichain $A_n$ in (1), we may consider the descending sequence $A_0^c>(A_0\cup A_1)^c>(A_0\cup A_1\cup A_2)^c>\cdots$ and then apply the argument from before about descending sequences. And similarly in the density case.

Comment: Could you please explain what "the famous construction of Hausdorff" is or give a reference to it?

Comment: I added a brief explanation. See also my essay on the orders of infinty at https://www.infinitelymore.xyz/p/the-orders-of-infinity.

Comment: Thanks for this really elegant argument!

Comment: Or "for every $n$ except $0$"? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I start my enumerations with 0.

Comment: So the $0\text{th}$ element of $A_0$ is . . .  $\qquad$

Comment: ...the least element of $A_0$. This is the index when you enumerate it in order $a_0,a_1,a_2,$ and so forth. But if you want to start at $n=1$, the construction will also work fine.

Comment: ok,  Got it. $\qquad$

Comment: One may say that "the famous construction of Hausdorff" is a species of the diagonal argument. Indeed, if the elements of the set $A_0\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ are $b_{n,0}<b_{n,1}<\cdots$, then $A=\{b_{0,0},b_{1,1},\ldots\}$.

Comment: Actually this argument is very natural because if trying to prove that the answer is positive, essentially the only thing to show is that every decreasing sequence of nonzero element has a nonzero lower bound (Parovicenko characterization of BAs isomorphic to $2^\omega/$fin under CH). Once one tries to do so, one sees that the density provides an obvious obstruction.